# Call a method whenever a property is called

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, attributes

Is there a way to add a attribute or something to a class that whenever a property of that class gets called that a method will be called?

Basically i have classes that contains a datarow and instead of accessing the individual column like:(DataRow["some_column_name"]) I want to access them using properties instead like: (MyClass.some_column_name).

My current work around is using reflection to dynamically pass the columns name as parameters like so:

```
public string some_column_name
    {
        get
        {

            return (string)GetValue(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value);
        }
    }
```

The problem with the above mentioned way is if i have a class with 10 properties inside of it all these properties will have the above code snippet in them bloating the class.

Below code sample contains the get and set value method of the above code snippet these methods would be in the base class:

```
private DataRow some_table;

protected object GetValue(string columnName)
{
    return some_table[columnName.Substring(columnName.IndexOf('_') + 1)];
}

protected object SetValue(string columnName, object value)
{
    return  some_table[columnName.Substring(columnName.IndexOf('_') + 1)] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a simple working version of your code using `PostSharp AOP`. Result here would be **TestProperty**, as we trim `get_` and `set_`. There's much more processing possible in the `OnInvoke`, the `MethodInterceptionArgs` can be used to make lot of modifications to the caller, then we can choose to return from PostSharp call itself or further execute the method. You can also plan to use AOP functions like `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`, which can execute on success or failure of a method

```
namespace TestAOP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var t = new Test();

           var x = t.TestProperty;

           Console.WriteLine(x);

           Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private string _test = "InitialValue";

        [CustomProperty]
        public string TestProperty
        {
            get => _test;
            set => _test = value;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class CustomPropertyAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
    {
        public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
        {
           args.ReturnValue = args.Method.Name.Substring(args.Method.Name.IndexOf("_", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[CallerMemberName]` attribute. If you decorate method parameter with this attribute like this:

```
protected object GetValue([CallerMemberName] string columnName = null)
{
    return some_table[columnName.Substring(columnName.IndexOf('_') + 1)];
}

protected object SetValue(object value, [CallerMemberName] string columnName = null)
{
    return  some_table[columnName.Substring(columnName.IndexOf('_') + 1)] = value;
}
```

Compiler will use, well, caller member (method) name instead of default null value. So your property becomes just:

```
public string some_column_name
{
    get
    {
        // current method name ("some_column_name") will be passed 
        // as "column" parameter
        return (string)GetValue();
    }
    set
    {
        // same here
        SetValue(value);
    }
}
```

Another alternative might be to inherit from `DynamicObject`:

```
public class DynamicRow : DynamicObject {
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        // this will be called when you access dynamic property
        // like x.some_column_name
        result = GetValue(binder.Name);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        // this will be called when you assign dynamic property
        // like x.some_column_name = "some value"
        SetValue(binder.Name, value);
        return true;
    }

    private DataRow some_table;

    protected object GetValue(string columnName) {
        return some_table[columnName.Substring(columnName.IndexOf('_') + 1)];
    }

    protected object SetValue(string columnName, object value) {
        return some_table[columnName.Substring(columnName.IndexOf('_') + 1)] = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
dynamic x = new DynamicRow();
object val = x.some_column_name;
x.some_column_name = "some value";
```

But I personally don't quite like it, because you are losing all type safety (any typo will only be caught at runtime), compared to using static list of properties like in the first approach.

Comment: This definitely cleans up the classes allot if i don't find a different solution, thanks!

Comment: @GysRademeyer I've added one more alternative (though I consider first one is better)

Comment: I agree with the type safety you mentioned, the first answer is feels better. If i went the second answers route it would basically be the same as using the datarow as is without the [""].

Comment: Yes, so I think there is no better way than first. To achieve safety you anyway have to list all valid property names manually. With AOP tools like PostSharp you can eliminate boilerplate GetValue and SetValue, but probably not worth it in this case.

Comment: If you want to simplify the getter/setter code further, take a look at expression bodied members in C#. That should compress every property into a one-liner.

Comment: @AshleyPillay thats a good idea, unfortunately i am bound to C#6 and those expressions require c#7

Comment: @Evk someone mentioned AOP to me earlier as-well, il have a look at it and see if its maybe what i need. Will let you know. thanks!